# Angular unable to execute setTimeout on DoCheck hook

Tags: angular

I'm testing for changes in every cycle and apply a certain class upon calculated value. I need to remove this class after 1 second. Currently the app freezes and I cant understand why.
Here's the code:

```
  ngDoCheck():void {
     const posClass = "positive-change";
     const negClass = "negative-change";
     const that = this;

     if(this.value1 - this.value2> 0){
        this.color = posClass;
      }else{
        this.color = negClass;
      }
      setTimeout(() => 
      {
        this.color = "default";
      },500);
  }
```

This works well without the timeout. I'm just unable to remove the class after the delay. How can this be solved?

Comment: Are you developing a stock-ticker?

Comment: could you try wrapping `this.color = "default";` inside a `NgZone.run`

Comment: Tried, its stuck. The timeout somehow causes to some sort of freeze